# How does RandomForestClassifier work for classification?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, random-forest, multiclass-classification

I have learned that Sklearn treats multi-class classification problems as a collection of binary problems. Quoting the Sklearn user guide:

> In extending a binary metric to multiclass or multilabel problems, the data is treated as a collection of binary problems, one for each class.

So, binary classification models like `LogisticRegression` or Support vector matrices can support multi-class cases by using either One-vs-One or One-vs-Rest strategies. I wanted to know if that was the case for `RandomForestClassifier` too? How about other classifiers in Sklearn - are they all used as binary classifiers under the hood when dealing with a multi-class problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation for [Decision Trees](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#multi-output-problems), multi-output problems add a small change to the leaves of each tree in a random forest.

Suppose you have set `criterion='gini'`. In essence, each node is built by picking a subset of `max_features` features, calculating the average reduction in the gini impurity for all N classes and choosing the variable-threshold combination that reduces it most.

This means that random forests do not create one model for each class. Instead, it's only one model that simultaneously reduces the criterion metric for all classes in each node of every tree and predicts the most common class at each leaf.